# Поиск в ассоциативном массиве по 2м параметрам

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

задача следующая, есть подобный массив, необходимо вернуть ключ, где 'parent_id' - например равен 1, и 'order' - минимален, т.е. я должен по данным условиям получить индекс массива [2]

```
1 => [
    'id' => '1'
    'parent_id' => '79'
    'order' => '1
]
2 => [
    'id' => '2'
    'parent_id' => '1'
    'order' => '1'
]
3 => [
    'id' => '3'
    'parent_id' => '1'
    'order' => '3'
]
4 => [
    'id' => '4'
    'parent_id' => '1'
    'order' => '2'
]
```

Comment: фильтр вначале по parent_id, потом среди оставшихся взять с минималкой

Answer (score 0):

```
$parentId = 1;
$needIndex = null;

$minOrder = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($arr as $index => $item) {
    if ($item['parent_id'] != $parentId) continue; //Пропускаем неподходящие элементы
    if ($item['order'] < $minOrder) {
        $needIndex = $index;
        $minOrder = $item['order'];
    }
}

echo $needIndex;
```

Comment: зачем городить эту вложенность и усложнять читаемость кода?  `if($item['parent_id' != $pid) continue;` дальше простой минимум ищите

Comment: user3265030, спасибо, проверил код работает так как нужно.

Comment: teran, можно уже законченное решение?

Comment: @teran, полностью согласен. Так как вы говорите будет гораздо читабильнее. :)

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=array('1'=>[
    'id' => '1',
    'parent_id' => '79',
    'order' => '1'
],
'2' => [
    'id' => '2',
    'parent_id' => '1',
    'order' => '1'
],
'3' => [
    'id' => '3',
    'parent_id' => '1',
    'order' => '3'
],
'4' => [
    'id' => '4',
    'parent_id' => '1',
    'order' => '2'
]);

print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  # code...
if($value['parent_id']=='1'){

$arr[]=$value['order'];
$row=min($arr);

if($value['order']==$row){

  $keey=$key;
}

}



}

echo "<br>";
print_r($data[$keey]);
?>
```